# Test connection only works after anypoint studio restart

Tags: db2, mule, mule-studio, sqlexception, anypoint-studio

I am trying to connect to a db2 database from anypoint studio using generic database configuration of the database connector . However , using the database url i am able to get test connection successful but this worked only one time .Then i noticed this test connection works only after i restart the anypoint studio.

Here is the message i am receiving:
org.mule.module.db.internal.domain.connection.connection creationexception java.sql.SQLException :Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

If all the connection parameters are correct and DB is up and running. Better to raise a JIRA ticket with MuleSoft.

https://www.mulesoft.org/jira